# Displaying auto incremented column values(Identity Feature) in DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, datagridview

I have a table in Sql Server 2008 where I am using Identity feature to auto increment values as soon as a new row is added.I want to display the entire column of auto incremented values on a DataGridView.

Following is my code that I am using to populate the GridView

```
public void LoadOnlyLeadMasters()
        {
            try
            {
                DS_Main.Tables["LeadMasters"].Clear();
                string query = "SELECT * FROM LeadMasters";
                cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, con);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, con);
                adp.Fill(DS_Main, "LeadMasters");
            }
            catch (Exception E)
            {
                ErrorLog(E);
            }
        }

 public void DisplayingGridView()
        {
             Mainform = new Form1(Login);
             Mainform.LoadOnlyLeadMasters();
             Display_dataGridView1.DataSource = Form1.DS_Main.Tables["LeadMasters"];
            //Display_dataGridView1.DataMember = "LeadMasters";

            for (int i = 0; i < Display_dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                Display_dataGridView1.Columns[i].Visible = false;
            }


            Display_dataGridView1.Columns["CompanyName"].Visible = true;
            Display_dataGridView1.Columns["PersonName"].Visible = true;
            Display_dataGridView1.Columns["Number"].Visible = true;
            Display_dataGridView1.Columns["Emailaddress"].Visible = true;
            Display_dataGridView1.Columns["Product"].Visible = true;
            Display_dataGridView1.Refresh();
        }
```

I hope I have provided enough information about the issue.If not do let me know

Thanks

Comment: Not an error @MairajAhmad.I wish to display auto incremented values  generated in table to a DataGridView, can you tell me the technique to achieve this/?

Comment: simply bind gridview with the data containing that column.